# What is a possible substitution to this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this ODE:

$$
(y-2x)\frac{dy}{dx}=3y-6x+1
$$

I have to make it in a form of separable variable equation and for that I have tried the following substitutions:
$$
u=y-2x
$$
and
$$
u=3y-6x+1
$$

But none made it "solvable", for example in the first I get to a point where I have this:
$$
\frac{e^{y-2x}}{|y-2x|}=x+K
$$
where K is any constant. At this point I am unable to solve for y.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(y-2x)\frac{dy}{dx}=3y-6x+1$$
Substitute $y-2x=z \implies y'-2=z'$
$$z(z'+2)=3z+1$$
$$zz'=z+1$$
$$\int \frac {zdz}{z+1}=x+K$$
$$z-\ln (z+1)=x+K$$
$$y -\ln(y-2x+1)=3x+K$$
Implicit form is correct too. So you can keep it this way

Or consider x as a function of y
$$x(y)=\frac 13(y-\ln(y-2x+1))+c$$

Comment: That's what I had gotten to, but I didn't know I could leave it in the implicit form. By the way, if I was given the condition $$y(x_0)=y_0$$ how could I find the maximal solution with the implicit form?

Comment: If this is homework, whether you can "leave it in the implicit form" or not depends upon your teacher!  Ask him or her.  As for "$y(x_0)= y_0$". since you have $y- ln(y- 2x+ 1)= 3x+ K$, replace y with $y_0$ and x with $x_0$:  $y_0- ln(y_0- 2x_0+ 1)= 3x_0+ K$ so that $K= y_0- 3x_0-  ln(y_0- 2x_0+ 1)$ and  $y- ln(y- 2x+ 1)= 3x+ y_0- 3x_0-  ln(y_0- 2x_0+ 1)$.

Answer (score 4):

*Starting from Isham's answer*.

Using
$$3x+c=y-\ln(y-2x+1)$$ the explicit solution is given by
$$y=-W\left(-e^{-(x+c+1)}\right)+2 x-1$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Using the condition $y(x_0)=y_0$, we get
$$c=-\log \left(-(2 x_0-y_0-1)\, e^{(2 x_0-y_0-1)}\right)-x_0-1$$ and then
$$y=-W\left((2 x_0-y_0-1) e^{(3 x_0-y_0-x-1)}\right)+2 x-1$$